# SQL Query to get misc column information

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I needed to write a query where I can get info about all columns (with data type) and also to know which ones are `PK/FK`. For `FK`, needed the additional info like which other table is it from. **I have got the query which works**, but it looks a bit overkill.

Can this be done better way? **I don't like the sub-query joins in it**. It has to be a query, can't be done via `SP`.

My example is against `Northwind` (with some additional `FK` relationships that I was testing)

```
SELECT 
    t.name AS TableName, 
    t.object_id AS TableObjectId,
    tCols.column_name AS ColumnName, 
    tCols.data_type AS ColumnDataType, 
    ISNULL(tCols.numeric_scale, 0) AS ColumnDecimalPlaces,
    CASE tConstraints.CONSTRAINT_TYPE
        WHEN 'PRIMARY KEY'
            THEN '1'
            ELSE '0'
    END AS ISPK, 
    CASE tConstraints.CONSTRAINT_TYPE
        WHEN 'FOREIGN KEY'
            THEN '1'
            ELSE '0'
    END AS ISFK, 
    tConstraints.CONSTRAINT_TYPE,
    tConstraints.CONSTRAINT_NAME,
    fkInfo.FK_name,
    fkInfo.PK_column,
    fkInfo.PK_table,
    fkInfo.PK_name
FROM sys.objects t
LEFT JOIN information_schema.columns tCols ON tCols.TABLE_NAME = t.name 
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT  
        tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME, 
        tc.TABLE_NAME, 
        tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE, 
        kcu.COLUMN_NAME
    FROM information_schema.table_constraints tc
    INNER JOIN  information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
) AS tConstraints
     ON t.name = tConstraints.TABLE_NAME
    AND tCols.column_name = tConstraints.COLUMN_NAME
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        o1.name AS FK_table,
        c1.name AS FK_column,
        fk.name AS FK_name,
        o2.name AS PK_table,
        c2.name AS PK_column,
        pk.name AS PK_name
    FROM sys.objects o1
    INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys fk
        ON o1.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
        ON fk.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c1
         ON fkc.parent_object_id = c1.object_id
        AND fkc.parent_column_id = c1.column_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c2
         ON fkc.referenced_object_id = c2.object_id
        AND fkc.referenced_column_id = c2.column_id
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o2
        ON fk.referenced_object_id = o2.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.key_constraints pk
         ON fk.referenced_object_id = pk.parent_object_id
        AND fk.key_index_id = pk.unique_index_id
) AS fkInfo ON t.name = fkInfo.FK_table
    AND tCols.column_name = fkInfo.FK_column
WHERE t.name = 'Products'
ORDER BY 3
```

[image: This is the output]

Comment: That is about what it takes to do *all* you want.  You could conceal the complexity by making it into a stored procedure.

Comment: @wallyk this is a generic piece of software for a client rich Grid control. So SP option wouldn't work. Good comment though, I will add that in the question.

Comment: You should not join by names.

Comment: how about CTE in single query ?

Comment: This is really not that terrible. Can you just make this thing into a view, so you can `SELECT * FROM my_view WHERE tablename='Products';` in your front-end software? I mean... like what's so bad about this query? I've seen much more complex sql in the last hour alone.

Comment: subqueries can be converted into CTEs

Comment: A couple of comments about using CTE. Not sure how would it help in this situation?

Comment: Curious that you're concerned about the complexity and "don't like the sub-query joins", yet you use the clear-as-a-bell feature `ORDER BY 3`.

Comment: You can use parens to force the inner joins to happen before the outer joins. That would eliminate the need to use the derived tables/subqueries.

Comment: @shawnt00 Parenthesis will not force the optimizer to form a plan in any particular sequence. It is free to unravel nesting and re-structure the query in any way it chooses, so long as the logic is maintained. Same with CTEs; the optimizer is free to integrated them into the body of the query in any logically equivalent way.

Comment: @Michael You're right. I meant the syntax: `A left join (B inner join C on C.id = B.id) on B.id = A.id`. The parens aren't strictly necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try my query (i have pk_name and fk_name in separated column, so don't need case), it is on system views, and it is fast:

```
with 
  pk as (select pki.object_id, pki.column_id, _pk.name 
      from sys.index_columns pki  
      join sys.key_constraints _pk 
      on _pk.unique_index_id = pki.index_id and _pk.parent_object_id = pki.object_id
      where 1=1),
  fk as (select fkc.parent_object_id, fkc.parent_column_id, fk.name name, pkt.name pk_table, pkc.name pk_column, pkc.object_id, pkc.column_id
    from sys.foreign_keys as fk
    join sys.tables pkt
    on pkt.object_id = fk.referenced_object_id
    join sys.foreign_key_columns as fkc
    on fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
    join sys.columns as pkc
    on pkc.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id and pkc.column_id = fkc.referenced_column_id
    where 1=1)
select t.name TableName
, t.object_id TableObjectId
, c.column_id CId
, c.name AS ColumnName
, typ.name AS ColumnDataType
, c.is_identity
, c.precision
, c.scale
, pk.name pk_name
, fk.name fk_name
, fk.pk_table
, fk.pk_column
, fkpk.name pk_for_fk
from sys.tables as t
inner join sys.columns as c on t.object_id = c.object_id
inner join sys.types as typ on typ.user_type_id = c.user_type_id
left join pk on pk.object_id = t.object_id and pk.column_id = c.column_id
left join fk on fk.parent_object_id = c.object_id and fk.parent_column_id = c.column_id
left join pk as fkpk on fkpk.object_id = fk.object_id and fkpk.column_id = fk.column_id
WHERE t.name = 'Products'
```

Answer (score 5):

> but it looks a bit overkill

If you want to pull a lot of values from a lot of tables then you are going to end up with a large query. That's just how it works. As these things go, this one isn't that large.

Are you concerned that SQL Server can't handle it? Don't be, it can. Performance? Not a lot you can do since these are internal catalog tables. Refactoring options are limited since you require a single statement and SPs are out. Wrapping it as an inline table valued function may help, but may hurt performance if it goes wrong.

If you just want clarity in the presentation of the SQL, the sub-queries could be written as CTEs, converted to views (or functions, but don't) or unnested so all joins are at the same indentation level. The latter is more likely to obscure than to elucidate, however.

On balance I think your best hope is to write clean code - good indentation, consistent naming, reasonable aliases etc. - and describe objectives and techniques in comments. What you have presented achieves most of this.

Comment: I agree, but would add that sometimes it is good to split a large query like this into multiple queries, populate a temporary table with the results of each query, then query the table to get the results. This sometimes speeds up the process and can make it much more readable and maintainable.